# Declare the nativeptr<unit> type

Tags: f#, interop, native, c#-to-f#, unit-type

I'd like to know if it's possible in F# to declare the type:

```
nativeptr<unit>
```

This seems not possible (compiler complains with *"A generic construct requires that the type 'unit' is an unmanaged type"*). Is there a workaround I could use?

The ultimate goal is to declare my own blitDelegate for exposing the opcode `Cpblk` to some of my F# code.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here's what I've tried based on kvb's answer:

```
type blitDelegate<'T when 'T : unmanaged> = delegate of nativeptr<'T> * nativeptr<'T> * uint32 -> unit

let createBlitDelegate<'T when 'T : unmanaged>() =
    let dm = new DynamicMethod("blit",
                               typeof<System.Void>,
                               [| typeof<nativeptr<'T>>; typeof<nativeptr<'T>>; typeof<uint32> |])
    let ilGenerator = dm.GetILGenerator()
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2)
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Cpblk)
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
    dm.CreateDelegate(typeof<blitDelegate<'T>>) :?> blitDelegate<'T>

let blit (blitDel:blitDelegate<'T>) dst src byteWidth = blitDel.Invoke(dst, src, byteWidth)
```

Then I call this code from a class member like that:

```
let dst = //get nativeint destination address
let src = //get nativeint source address

let bd = createBlitDelegate<'T>()

let tdst = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<'T> dst
let tsrc = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<'T> src

do blit bd tdst tsrc (uint32 size)
//Program.MemCpy.Invoke(dst.ToPointer(), dst.ToPointer(), uint32 size)
```

This results in a runtime error at blit (*System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.*)

The commented code works well (and can be found [here](http://www.abstractpath.com/weblog/2009/04/memcpy-in-c.html)) but my point was to code it in F# (not C#).

The reason why I wanted to use at first a `nativeptr<unit>` is that it is actually the type of the two first arguments of `MemCpy` delegate (that matches `void*` type) and somewhat wanted to mimic it.

**Edit2:**

Based on kvb's edit, I modified my code to host the delegate creation in a type using static members (like the C# version) and it now works.
I don't use the version with the unmanaged constraint but this one, since I actually need to blit array of structs:

```
type blitDelegate = delegate of nativeint * nativeint * uint32 -> unit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it's not clear to me why you'd like a `nativeptr<unit>`.  Essentially, `nativeptr<'t>` is just a thin wrapper over `nativeint` with some helpers for doing arithmetic on the pointer.  Since you're unlikely to have an array of `unit`s, I don't see how this actually helps you, though.  Perhaps if you show more of your code it will be easier to give a more satisfactory answer.

**EDIT**

I think you're doing almost everything right.  However, anonymously hosted `DynamicMethod`s must be verifiable, and the `cpblk` opcode is never verifiable.  Try using a different constructor for `DynamicMethod` to host it on a type or module.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another tip: if you want the **IL** `cpblk` instruction to support the standard .NET array **covariance** on managed pointers when using an (e.g.) `TDerived[]` array *source* to`TBase[]` *destination*, then you must create the source `ref` (only) with so-called "controlled mutability" by placing the `OpCodes.Readonly` prefix immediately before the `OpCodes.Ldelema` instruction. Otherwise, if the actual type of source array has a derived element type you'll crash with `ArrayTypeMismatchException` exception ***"Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array"*** .

Comment: ... The IL for (e.g.) covariantly copying one `!T` element from `srcArr[ix]` to `!T& pDst` ends up looking like this: `ldarg pDst; ldarg srcArr; ldarg ix; readonly. ldelema !T; sizeof !T; cpblk`